# Unable to get the params inside controller in li3 commands in php8

Tags: php-8, lithium

I am writing an simple li3 command code as shown below

```
namespace app\commands;

use lithium\console\Command;

class HelloCommand extends Command {

public function run() {

print_r($this->request);

$this->out("Hello, Lithium!");

}

}
```

In command line

```
bin/li3 HelloCommand --paramId=12345
```

I am trying to get the paramId parameter, that I have given in command, but that params is not showing at the controller side. In php7 with the same code I am able to read the params, after migrating from php7 to php8, I am facing this issue.

Any suggestions or help please on this thanks, Should I have to do any changes from controller/framework side?